# Use regex preg_match to find opening anchor tag and grab class attribute

Tags: php, regex, class, preg-match, anchor

What I am simply trying to do is take the following code:

```
$Anchors = '<a href="#" class="test1"><div class="test2"><a href="#" class="test3"><div class="test4">'
```

And get the value of the class attribute of the last anchor tag, in this case "test3." So far I have this:

```
if(preg_match('/(<a\s.*)(class="|\')([^-\'"]*)("|\')?.*?([^>])/i',$Anchors,$matches)){
```

But obviously its not doing what I want it to do, any help?

Comment: Obligatory "don't use regex to parse HTML" comment.

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. ... O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This regular expression will:

- match the last anchor tag from your string
- capture the value for the class attribute
- avoid many of the potential problems with using regex to when searching html strings

```
.*<a\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sclass=['"]([^"]*)['"]?)  # capture the src attribute value
(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?> # get the entire  tag
```

[image]

## Example

Live example here: http://www.rubular.com/r/G5F6AD5UyL

**Sample text**

note that the last tag has a difficult edge case

```
<a href="#" class="test1"><div class="test2">
<a onmouseover=' class="NotTheClass" ; funClassRotator(class) ; ' class="test3" href="#" ><div class="test4">
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0][0] = <a href="#" class="test1"><div class="test2"><a href="#" onmouseover=' class="NotTheClass" ; funClassRotator(class) ; ' class="test3">
[0][1] = test3
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster using [ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/) or [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

For example using simplehtmldom

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
   echo $element->class . '<br>';
```